Unity 2022.3.19 Webgl iOS RAM refreshes
Environment: Unity 2022.3.19, WebGL, mobile Safari. The game consumes a significant amount of RAM on iOS.

The main issue is that the game randomly reloads when switching scenes. I suspect this might be due to memory spikes or excessive RAM usage.
The game is a 2D project utilizing Spine animations and a large number of textures. All textures are compressed with ASTC 10x10.
Additionally, audio clips are streamed to avoid loading them fully into RAM.
I'm unsure if it's possible to compress the JSON data used by Spine animations to reduce memory usage.
I read that Safari refreshes the page when it exceeds 384 MB of RAM, but the game seems to stay within that limit.
Does anyone have insights on how this works or suggestions for reducing JavaScript RAM consumption? Any advice would be appreciated!
